# Basic HTML/CSS - Can't center

Tags: html, css

I'm brand new to learning HTML and CSS and I'm messing around with a simple site to embed videos I often use for stretching. But I cant seem to center the 2nd h2 tag (Evening) to be centered along with everything else. I thought the body css text-align:center value would take care of it like it did the first h2 tag (Morning). Here is the HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #727070;
}

p {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.float {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div>
    <h1>Stretches</h1>
  </div>

  <h2>Morning:</h2>

  <div class="float">
    <p>Molding Mobility
      <p>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Aoyy3bKtD84" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>



  <div class="float">
    <p>Horse Stances</p>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kXWtk3NLESk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>


  <h2>Evening:</h2>

  <div class="float">
    <p>Hip Mobility</p>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NG9qbvAN3gQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>



  <div class="float">
    <p>Starting Stretching</p>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w1iXMvTMvBo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: At a glance, it looks like this could be an issue caused by *uncleared floats*. Declare the following rule and let me know if it resolved the issue; `h2 {clear: both;}`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, you're right. Adding this rule solves the problem.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the follow-up. Have a rocking day now.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, Thanks this also fixed it up! I'll learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #727070;
}

p {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.float {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.25%;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}

.clearfloat {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div>
    <h1>Stretches</h1>
  </div>

  <h2>Morning:</h2>
  <div style="height:400px;">
    <div class="clearfloat">
      <div class="float">
        <p>Molding Mobility
          <p>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Aoyy3bKtD84" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>



      <div class="float">
        <p>Horse Stances</p>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kXWtk3NLESk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 align="center">Evening:</h2>
  <div class="clearfloat">
    <div class="float">
      <p>Hip Mobility</p>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NG9qbvAN3gQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>



    <div class="float">
      <p>Starting Stretching</p>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w1iXMvTMvBo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: try the above solution

Comment: You should edit your first answer instead of posting 2 answers. You should also describe what you changed rather than just posting code and saying try it.

Comment: @csm_dev sorry about that. i have enclose first two div with class clearfloat to and gave a height to that div

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you float an element you take it out of the flow, meaning that its parent will collapse and everything coming after it will be in the wrong position. A quick fix for it is to add a container to the floated elements and give it `overflow: hidden;`.

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #727070;
}

p {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.float {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.25%;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}

.clearfloat {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div>
    <h1>Stretches</h1>
  </div>

  <h2>Morning:</h2>

<div class="clearfloat">
  <div class="float">
    <p>Molding Mobility
      <p>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Aoyy3bKtD84" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>



  <div class="float">
    <p>Horse Stances</p>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kXWtk3NLESk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

  <h2>Evening:</h2>
<div class="clearfloat">
  <div class="float">
    <p>Hip Mobility</p>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NG9qbvAN3gQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>



  <div class="float">
    <p>Starting Stretching</p>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w1iXMvTMvBo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This fixed it up perfectly. Also thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Just add Float left to the Second h2 tag

```
<h2 style="float:left;">Evening:</h2>
```

Comment: If you did what you described, then it works. If you use the code you provided, it does not. Now it is better.

Comment: i just mention that in the  2nd h2 add float left according to his question

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned its due to incorrect placement of floating elements, please adjust the html to look like below, also you need to use a wrapping div with the class `clearfix` on the floating children. Please read [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) for more details on clearfix.

I have also adjusted the `iframe` to `width="100%"`, so that it will always take height of the parent `div`.

Note: Please click on the `Full Page` link in the snippet, for a better view of how the output will look

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #727070;
}

p {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.float {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

```html
<body>

  <div>
    <h1>Stretches</h1>
  </div>

  <h2>Morning:</h2>
  <div class="clearfix">

  <div class="float">
    <p>Molding Mobility
      <p>
        <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Aoyy3bKtD84" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>



  <div class="float">
    <p>Horse Stances</p>
    <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kXWtk3NLESk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  </div>


  <h2>Evening:</h2>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="float">
      <p>Hip Mobility</p>
      <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NG9qbvAN3gQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>



    <div class="float">
      <p>Starting Stretching</p>
      <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w1iXMvTMvBo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use clear property as you used  `float`

Simply do one thing :

```
<h2 style="clear:both">Evening:</h2>
```

For more information: you can take a look at this [Clear:both property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clear/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add following:

1. Before `<h2>Evening:</h2>` add `<div class="clear"></div>`
2. In CSS add following rule:

   ```
   .clear {
     clear: both;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -3):

try adding align center attribute

```
align="center"
```

or

```
add css text-align:center;
```

Comment: We prefer answers that actually solve the problem, not just suggestions that, like in this case, don't work.

Comment: this is sync problem i just comment before.